# WPF edit path size, position and convert to geometry

Tags: c#, wpf

I was coding my own Overlay-Content FrameworkElement in WPF.

I must do resize and set position to center to Combine with RectangleGeometry

but I can't found Resize Path content and set position

and also can't found how to convert path to geometry.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyHelper.Register(
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Overlay Content", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public object Content
    {
        get => this.GetValue<object>(ContentProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
```

It is my Content DependencyProperty.

I get content path in xaml like this.

```
        <c:OverlayedContent Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <c:OverlayedContent.Content>
                <Path
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Data="{StaticResource Path.Music}"\ />
            </c:OverlayedContent.Content>
        </c:OverlayedContent>
```

in OnRender

```
var path = (Path)Content;
var contentGeometry = path.RenderedGeometry;

var rectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight), RadiusX, RadiusY);
var combined = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Xor, rectangleGeometry, contentGeometry);

var visualColor = new SolidColorBrush(Foreground);

drawingContext.DrawGeometry(visualColor, null, combined);
```

Comment: As a note, the whole `if (visualColor.Color.A >= 255)` is pointless. `A` is of type `byte`, and hence never greater than 255. You should also declare the Foreground property as `Brush`, so you could directly write `DrawGeometry(Foreground, ...)`.

Comment: @Clemens Oh I missed that. thx.